# Are there limitations for hosting files on github.io?

Tags: github-pages

I created a small gh-page at http://s-a.github.io/sample-db/ which contains an audio player pointing to wav files in a sub folder. Any request on a wave file returns `404`. Are there any limitations for hosting files on github.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with file size, they are under the 100MB limit ([see github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/))

Your problem come from the fact that github page server is `case sensitive`.

In your `channel.json` file, your naming scheme is `bpnet_something`. But your files are named with the scheme `bpNet_something`.

Change **bpnet** to **bpNet** in file names in your `channel.json` file, commit, push and listen to the music.